# Edit Product Meta Data after adding to cart in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, forms, woocommerce, gravity

I a using Woocommerce, Gravity Forms with WooCommerce - Gravity Forms Product Add-Ons plugin. They allow me to fill the form and get a product with metadata from the GF form. Now, I need the cart item to be editable after the form is submitted and product is added to WC cart. 
Ideal solution would be a way to get back to the form and have everything already prepopulated there, so I can edit the data and update the cart item that way.

Does anyone know about any working solution for that?

Here is the website you can see it in action: 
http://www.cledu.ca/disc-jockey-coverage/

Comment: any idea where to start? Can't find any plugin for that, so it looks like good niche.

Comment: Try giving links of your forms in the review orders section which is before check phase. Use a page which will get the form's id and as per the id it will generate fields with there values pre-populated.

Comment: When I add product to cart then its name on Cart links to page like that: 
http://www.cledu.ca/product/event-coverage-1-day/ - do you think it is a good start  point? Should I prepopulate values using GET? Will it update cart item or create a new one?

Comment: No, it will add second item to the cart, so I need to update a cart item in some way.